# change array values during foreach. Adding html element to every array item

Tags: php

I wanted to ask, how can i modify array values when doing foreach - in my example, i want to add  to every element, but this code produces error.

```
foreach ($logo as &$value) {
                $value = '<div>' . $value . '</div>';
                debug ($value);
            }
            ?>
```

and the error: Notice (8): Array to string conversion

I'm using php 5.6

Thanks for reply.

Comment: print $logo array before foreach
as per understanding this is multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
$serviceMe = ""; //OR use beginning html
foreach( $tmp as $t ) $serviceMe .= '<tr>' . $t . '</tr>';
$serviceMe .= ""; // Rest of the needed html
```

Make absolutely sure what type of is your $value. Is it integer,float,string,object,array... etc

I think your error comes from trying to convert array to string without proper handling.

```
$array = new array(
    'key'    => $value,
    'key2'    => $value2,
    'key3'    => $value3,
);
$string = "" . $array; //throws error!
```